# Azure function - func start giving error of Value cannot be null. Parameter name: provider

Tags: python, azure

```
You are using an outdated version of the Azure Functions Core Tools. For more information, 
please see: https://aka.ms/func-v2-upgrade
Found Python version 3.6.9 (python3).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       2.7.3188 Commit hash: f5984038c7377e9437f71191bff1d5818dd1fa8d
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.14786.0

AZURE_FUNCTIONS_ENVIRONMENT: Development
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: provider
```

When I run func start gives me the above error of value and parameter.
Appreciate the Help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reproduce the issue in my side and just remove a part of code in `host.json`, it works.

Remove this part of code:

[image]

And when the function can start success, then I restore the part of code in `host.json` and then it can also start success.

Comment: After starting the first time and restoring, I had to change the version to `"[1.*, 2.0.0)"`

Comment: Can you please explain this change?